# 12 to 6 look up table

Tags: cpu, ram, cache

I have an application where 12 input bits need to generate 6 output bits in a user configurable manner.  Of course this requires using a RAM based look up table.

I've noticed that the fastest static RAM available has an access time of about 10ns which limits the look up table access speed to 100 Mhz

How do microprocessors manage to access their internal caches in 1 clock cycle - typically 30 times faster than this?  Is the RAM chip speed being limited by it's external communication bus or is it something else?

Comment: Obviously.  The question already contained that information and asked why this was so, specifically what properties of cache RAM make it so fast, when it is computationally more complex to access since the access must go through checks done by a cache controller.

Comment: Sorry, I must have gotten blind or something.

Answer (score 2):

The on-chip cache memory is designed as part of the memory interface circuits and is optimised for speed at the expense of other considerations such as power consumption and die area that may make it impractical for larger sizes. It's also not generally accessible to the user so its addressing circuits and data paths can be simplified. All of that in combination with the lack of parasitic inductances and capacitances and the buffering needed to support off-chip access makes it considerably faster.

Tell us more about your application, as there may be other options available.

Comment: I wish to explore the possibility of producing a generic programmable computational device, n bits in width in which generates n bits of output.  2**k operations are to be supported.

Comment: I was more interested in the sort of application areas you were targeting that would require more than 100MHz of throughput?

Comment: Continued....  arbitrary selection of consecutive bits at the same time as any other operation
on any other independent consecutive sets of bits.

Comment: Purpose, General Computational. A general computational element to be used to replace multiple types of computational elements found in a microprocessor and to give unique flexibility in specifying additional instructions that are application specific.

Comment: Such a computational element can be made.  The question is, are transistors fast enough so that the settling time of the result is short enough to be practical?

Comment: By placing the opcode selection bits in the high order address bits, followed by inputs A, B and C, then only two bits remain to be cascaded. L and R,   Given that the upper bits have already converged on a solution, is there sufficient time to for 2 Least Significant selection bits to cascade over an n bit register?  I think so.  Would such an instruction need to be pipelined because it potentially takes more than 1 cycle?

Comment: Questions on whether things are going to be fast enough rather hinge on what "fast enough" means. If 100MHz isn't fast enough, what speed is it you ARE looking for?

Comment: This commenting system truly sucks.

Comment: Message system dropped a segment 2**k operations are to be supported.  Each bit takes as an input A, B  C, Li and Ri.  L and generates an output O,Lo,Ro,F  F is mapped to some flag register, C, OV, S, Z, etc.  Lo is sent to Ri of the next consecutive bit, and Ro is sent to the Li of the previous bit.

Comment: Your question was about how on-chip cache is quicker than off-chip RAM, I suggest you ask a new question specifically related to your design where you can ask it in better detail.